# SQL Server 2008 "Connect To Server" window hangs

Tags: sql-server-2008

I connect to a non-local instance of SQL server using MS SQL Server Management Studio.  The Login (on only one laptop) has recently started hanging.   I can login fine from another desktop using the exact same login.  So, I don’t think it’s a permissions issue.  (Server Type: Database Engine, Server name: Blahblah, Authentication: Windows Authentication).

I can also connect and run things on the server (from my laptop), through a connection using VBA.   I have previously been able to connect using the Studio just fine, and now I am unable for seemingly no reason.

I tried uninstalling, and reinstalling SQL Server, but it didn't work.  It's machine specific.  Any guidance would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "hanging", are you saying the login window doesnt return any exception info? Anything in the Event Viewer? Have you confirmed service credentials for the accounts SQL Server used on that laptop?

Comment: For "hanging", I mean that it doesn't return an error message.  The orange lines go across it, as though it's connecting, but it does nothing.  Even if I let it "connect" for 30 minutes.   I'm also entering a fully qualified name.  Event Viewer says "You are not connected to a server".   About "Service Credentials", I'm not sure how to reconfirm that, or if it's machine specific.    I don't know if it's possible that Windows Updates would change/destroy something like that.

Comment: Event Log "The description for Event ID 0 from source Self-service Plug-in cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Self-service Plug-in started (user=LOGON\xxxxxxxxx).

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

Comment: There's a Superuser question @Brando regarding a somewhat similar issue that seems to point to Citrix Receiver. Do you have this, or any other Citrix product installed?

Comment: I do have a Citrix product installed, and now that you say it, I used it for the first time, in a long time, and shortly (possibly the next day) after that the SQL Server Management Studio wouldn't connect.

Comment: here is the question @Brando:  http://superuser.com/questions/487411/identifying-windows-service - the resolution seems to be uninstall the Citrix product, after that... hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on SSMS icon and say "Run As Administrator".  Then used my same old login, and it worked fine.